# picking results from sql table on basic of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i am apicking a record from data base on basis of many condition but now i am stuck in one condition which i want to implement, first see the code.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Report_SmsTwentyFourhours_sdpo_Sp]

    @ParentID int

AS
BEGIN

    Declare @MaxID bigint
    Set @MaxID = (Select Max(ID) from SdpoReplies_SmsComplaints where ParentSmsID= @ParentID)

    Declare @DateReceived DateTime
    Set @DateReceived= (Select Convert(varchar(17),SdpoReplies_SmsComplaints.ReceivingDateTime, 113) 
    from SdpoReplies_SmsComplaints 
    where ParentSmsID= @ParentID
    AND 
    SdpoReplies_SmsComplaints.ID = @MaxID)

    Declare @DateSent DateTime
    Set @DateSent = (Select SendMessages.SendingDateTime from SendMessages where BasicSmsID= @ParentID)

    Declare @TimeFrame int
    Set @TimeFrame = (Select DATEDIFF(hh, @DateSent, @DateReceived))

    Declare @Subject varchar(MAX)
    Set @Subject = (Select ReceivedMessages.Message from ReceivedMessages where ID= @ParentID)

    Declare @FromMobileNo varchar(20)
    Set @FromMobileNo = (Select ReceivedMessages.FromMobileNo from ReceivedMessages where ID= @ParentID)

    Declare @PoliceStation varchar(50)
    Set @PoliceStation = (Select CPOCMS.dbo.PoliceStations.PsName from CPOCMS.dbo.PoliceStations 
                           Inner Join CmsSMSDb.dbo.SendMessages
                           ON CmsSMSDb.dbo.SendMessages.Psi_ID = CPOCMS.dbo.PoliceStations.Psid 
                           where SendMessages.BasicSmsID= @ParentID)

    Declare @SdpoContact varchar(50)
    Set @SdpoContact = (Select CPOCMS.dbo.PoliceStations.sDpo_ContactNo from CPOCMS.dbo.PoliceStations
                        Inner Join CmsSMSDb.dbo.SendMessages
                        ON CmsSMSDb.dbo.SendMessages.Psi_ID = CPOCMS.dbo.PoliceStations.Psid 
                        where SendMessages.BasicSmsID= @ParentID)

    Declare @District varchar(20)
    Set @District= (Select CPOCMS.dbo.Districts.Name from CPOCMS.dbo.Districts
                    Inner Join CPOCMS.dbo.PoliceStations
                    ON CPOCMS.dbo.PoliceStations.District_ID =  CPOCMS.dbo.Districts.DistrictID
                    Inner Join CmsSMSDb.dbo.SendMessages
                    ON CmsSMSDb.dbo.SendMessages.Psi_ID= CPOCMS.dbo.PoliceStations.Psid
                    where CmsSMSDb.dbo.SendMessages.BasicSmsID= @ParentID)

    Select @ParentID as SmsID, @DateReceived as ReceivingDate, @Subject as ComplaintSubject,
     @FromMobileNo as IncommingNo, @PoliceStation as SDPOPoliceStation, @District as District , 
     @SdpoContact as SDPOContact, @TimeFrame as TimeFrame 
END
```

now i want to put it on basic of `SdpoReplies_SmsComplaints.ReceivingDateTime` like dates should fall between this
how to do it correctly ? in this case :

```
Select @ParentID as SmsID, @DateReceived as ReceivingDate, @Subject as ComplaintSubject,
         @FromMobileNo as IncommingNo, @PoliceStation as SDPOPoliceStation, @District as District , 
         @SdpoContact as SDPOContact, @TimeFrame as TimeFrame
```

Comment: Capitalize and spell check.  Do you mean basic or basis?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to put a predicate in your WHERE clause to limit your results based on a date range.  To do that, you just need to add a line like:

```
SELECT *
FROM SdpoReplies_SmsComplaints
WHERE 
  -- Add the following line to your WHERE clause:
  ReceivingDateTime BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2
```

This will include both endpoints.  Just be mindful/aware that if @Date1 & @Date2 are different datatype than ReceivingDateTime, your endpoints can be eliminated if some of your data is being implicitly cast from DATETIME to DATE for instance.

Comment: thanks sir but just check my updated question for what i am exactly asking

Comment: I updated my answer slightly.  It still is not clear what you are asking though.  The code you added is just setting local variables...

Comment: sir, the question is that i am picking multiple variable which are based on multiple condition, now at last statement i want to put a date range along with @ParentID, which should return on those records which falls between 2 dates

Comment: Where you are setting the @PoliceStation variable?  If that is a case, what is the column whose value needs to fall between 2 dates, and what are the 2 dates?

Comment: Set @PoliceStation = (Select CPOCMS.dbo.PoliceStations.PsName from CPOCMS.dbo.PoliceStations 
                           Inner Join CmsSMSDb.dbo.SendMessages
                           ON CmsSMSDb.dbo.SendMessages.Psi_ID = CPOCMS.dbo.PoliceStations.Psid 
                           where SendMessages.BasicSmsID= @ParentID)

Comment: ReceivingDate is that column, and 2 dates would be parameters that i am gonna set in future just below @ParentID

Comment: after 'WHERE SendMessages.BasicSmsID = @ParentID', you need to add a line like 'AND [column name] BETWEEN [date1] AND [date2]' like I said in my original answer